# Accessing nested elements in a Pandas dataframe with dictionary like structure

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame as follows

```
In [19]: data_frame
Out[19]: 
                    _id                                              hero
0  55c97138e5fecec26959f3b0  {u'info': {u'id': u'0001', u'name': u'superman'}}
```

In order to filer out the name filed of the entry I do the following list comprehension. Is there a far simpler way of doing this ? because this method will not scale for more nested attributes

```
In [27]: [y['name'] for y in [x['info'] for x in data_frame['hero']]]
Out[27]: [u'superman']
```

Any insight is much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I would think that a complex nested dictionary in a single field of a dataframe is not a very efficient way to store such data in general. Couldn't you split the information in the `hero` field to single columns? (`id`, `name`, `...`)

Comment: if so i would gest that the apply method is a good hint here but like @chris-sc i would suggest you to restructure your data model or have a look at pytables etc

Comment: Thank you both of you. Yes it would be efficient if the data model could have been changed, but in my case i do not have that luxury. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can unwrap your object into the DataFrame like this:

```
df[(['_id', 'name'])] = df.hero.apply(
    lambda x: pd.Series(x['info'].values(), index=x['info'].keys())
    )

   id                            name   _id  hero
0  55c97138e5fecec26959f3b0  superman  0001  {u'info': {u'id': u'0001', u'name': u'superman'}}
```

Then access the elements like columns instead.

Comment: Thank you i suppose i will use your way

Comment: @EshanM.Herath Is there anything missing in my answer that would make you accept it? Or is it not actually the answer you were looking for?

Comment: I was waiting to find out whether there is another way, since the lambda will be more complex if i have another nested level. Anyway I think this is acceptable for now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult to tell without more realistic data, but perhaps this will work:

```
>>> df.hero.apply(lambda x: x.get('info').get('name'))
0    superman
Name: hero, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like lamda function is the way to go