# How to access a dict column field in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Having the follow dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[30, 20, {'some_data': 30}]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

I would like to create a new column with the value of `some_data` value.
I was thinking something like:

```
df['new_column'] = df['c']['some_data']
```

Is there a simple way to do it?
In reality the dict would be more complex, I will have to get a nested value.

EDIT 1:

Here is a example where I have nested data, it's closer to real problem.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[30, 20, {'some_data': [{'other_data': 0}]}]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
# I would like to do something like:
df['new_column'] = df['c']['some_data'][0]['other_data']
```

Comment: Pandas is not made to support data in this structure. You'll likely save yourself a lot of trouble if you can find a better way to organise the data. Chained string accessors will work here `df['c'].str['some_data'].str[0].str['other_data']` but this is an expensive operation and _will_ impact overall performance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing nested elements in a Pandas dataframe with dictionary like structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932984/accessing-nested-elements-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-dictionary-like-structure)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the `.str` accessor:

```
df.c.str['some_data']

#0    30
#Name: c, dtype: int64
```

---

You can further chain `.str` for nested data access, given:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[30, 20, {'some_data': [{'other_data': 0}]}]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df
#    a   b                                   c
#0  30  20  {'some_data': [{'other_data': 0}]}
```

To access nested `other_data` field, you can do:

```
df.c.str['some_data'].str[0].str['other_data']
#0    0
#Name: c, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this: `y = [df['c'][df['c'].keys()[0]].values()]`

Answer (score 0):

Your example of what you are trying to do is rather close to what should be done. If I understand your question correctly, this snippet should work.

```
df['new_column'] = df['c'][0]['some_data'][0]['other_data']
```

If this is not the desired behaviour, then you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31932984/accessing-nested-elements-in-a-pandas-dataframe-with-dictionary-like-structure).